# Is there a way we can add new projects to existing GCP monitoring workspace via a API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, monitoring, workspace

I have multiple GCP projects, And I want to setup a multi-projects monitoring workspace for my environment. I would like to add all un-monitored projects to the workspace that I have already created, but via an API so that this job is automated.
Via console I know that it's possible using this link's setup (https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/workspaces/create#add-monitored-project) But how can I achieve this via an API?
Please can someone provide any inputs here.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage [Dashboard via API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/dashboards/api-dashboard), and list [services](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/services/list) in the workspace, but API does not support adding projects to a workspace.
You can find list of all API methods [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest).
If you think that functionality should be supported, you can file a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187228&template=0).

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for your information. These links are helpful.